# optimising toggle multple image and show and hide divs

Tags: jquery, html

I need of a little assistance in optimising code I found online http://jsfiddle.net/eD4BY/4/ . I would like to use this code for multiple images. I have tried duplication the code multiple times as seen below but I know it is not the best way possible. Can you guys assist me?
 I would like that when I click image one, the associated image1 description shows, when I click another image2 only image2 description shows. In my current code I have to click once to show an image and click on that same image to hide the description, otherwise clicking between multiple images I have all the descriptions being shown.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <img  src="images/team1default.png" id="team1btn"/>
          <br>
        </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
          <img  src="images/team2default.png" id="team2btn"/>
          <br>
        </div>


        </div>

        <div id="team1idd" class="display-none2">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>
          team 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante ligula, volutpat tincidunt tincidunt eget, pharetra id libero. Donec vitae tempus mi. Vivamus molestie tellus lacinia aliquet consequat. Suspendisse dictum consectetur risus sed aliquam.           <p> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="team2idd" class="display-none">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <p>
          team 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ante ligula, volutpat tincidunt tincidunt eget, pharetra id libero. Donec vitae tempus mi. Vivamus molestie tellus lacinia aliquet consequat. Suspendisse dictum consectetur risus sed aliquam.           <p> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

jQUERY

```
<script>

var btnone =   $('#team1btn');
var iddone = $('#team1idd');

btnone.click(function() {  
   iddone.toggle(800, function() {
      // change the button text according to the state of the "#idd" 
      if (iddone.hasClass('display-none2')) {
        btnone.attr('src', 'images/team1active.png'); 
          iddone.removeClass('display-none2');
              } else {
        btnone.attr('src', 'images/team1default.png');
          iddone.addClass('display-none2');
       }
    });
  });
</script>


<script>

var btnone =   $('#team1btn');
var iddone = $('#team1idd');

btnone.click(function() {  
   iddone.toggle(800, function() {
      // change the button text according to the state of the "#idd" 
      if (iddone.hasClass('display-none2')) {
        btnone.attr('src', 'images/team1active.png'); 
          iddone.removeClass('display-none2');
              } else {
        btnone.attr('src', 'images/team1default.png');
          iddone.addClass('display-none2');
       }
    });
  });
</script>

<script>



  var btn =   $('#team2btn');
var idd = $('#team2idd');

btn.click(function() {  
   idd.toggle(800, function() {
      // change the button text according to the state of the "#idd" 
      if (idd.hasClass('display-none')) {
        btn.attr('src', 'images/team2active.png'); 
          idd.removeClass('display-none');
              } else {
        btn.attr('src', 'images/team2default.png');
          idd.addClass('display-none');
       }
    });
  });


</script>
```

Comment: A short description of what you want to accomplish, gives you a much greater probability that you get a satisfactory answer. So, what do you want to do?

Comment: You don't seem to have any buttons in your html?

Comment: btn its just a variable name given to the id

Comment: I missed that the images had that id, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="display-none content" data-content="1">- Here my hidden content 1 -</div>
<div class="display-none content" data-content="2">- Here my hidden content 2 -</div>
<!-- Button -->
<img class="image" data-image="1" />
<img class="image" data-image="2" />
```

JS

```
var images = {
    1: {
        active: 'http://placekitten.com/g/100/150',
        default: 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'
    },
    2: {
        active: 'http://placekitten.com/g/150/150',
        default: 'http://placekitten.com/g/300/300'
    }
};

function setupImages() {
    for (var prop in images) {
         $('[data-image="' + prop + '"]').attr('src', images[prop].default);   
    }
}

setupImages();

$('.image').each(function (k, v) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.click(function () {
        var contentNum = $(this).data('image');
        var content = $('[data-content="' + contentNum + '"]');
        $('.content').slideUp(800);
        content.toggle(800, function () {
            setupImages();
            if (content.hasClass('display-none')) {
                self.attr('src', images[contentNum].active);
                content.removeClass('display-none');
            } else {
                self.attr('src', images[contentNum].default);
                content.addClass('display-none');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eD4BY/54/)

Comment: Hello, I checked the fiddle and it solves my descriptions problem thank you very much. However it changes all the initial images to the same image. I am using different images that has a deafult and active version. Is there anyway when imageonedefault is click shows imageoneactive and when image two is imagetwodefault is click shows imagetwoactive?

Comment: You would probably be best suited with using an object to store the info and looping through like this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eD4BY/54/) If you are satisfied, please select answer as correct. I will update my answer.

Comment: One additional thing when image is clicked active and then click again to default the descriptions remain showing... I am not sure if something is hindering the addclass display-none... anyway ideas?